# How to put custom type as an input parameter in a callable statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I need to use callable statement for a record table. I know how to pass arguments like string, int etc. You could just write

```
callableStatement.setString(1, variable);
callableStatement.setInt(2, variable);
```

But how do I do it for a custom type record list? I can think of creating a `struct` and somehow sending it but I have no idea about how to do it.

Here's the custom table and procedures I am going to use

```
type transaction is record(
     trans_id   varchar2(20)
    ,issuer_name varchar2(300)
    ,location_name varchar2(300)
    ,trans_date    date
    ,issue_date      date);
  type transaction_list is table of transaction;

  procedure set_transaction
  (
    caller_id     in varchar2
   ,trans_list   in transaction_list
   ,return_code out varchar2
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a record as a type.  You can use OBJECT instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TEST_REC AS OBJECT (
 id_ varchar2(30),
 name_ varchar2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE MY_TEST OF MY_TEST_REC;

create or replace package my_p is
  procedure proc(arg_  IN OUT MY_TEST_REC);
END;

create or replace package body my_p is
  procedure proc(arg_  IN OUT MY_TEST_REC)
  IS  
  BEGIN
    arg_.name_ := 'BAR';
  END;
END;
```

And then bind the object in your callable statement to a Struct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [callableStatement.setObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) alongside a [Struct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Struct.html) type.

A good example of this can be found in the `_demoInsertUsingCallableStmt` method in this page:  [StructInsertExample](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/__/st/StructInsertExample.java.html)